# ¿Cómo volver a ejecutar una función asincrona con router.refresh()?

Tags: next.js, ssrs

tengo un problema al volver a renderizar una tabla que esta del lado del cliente, cuando se crea una nueva fila en una base de datos, ambos componentes estan separados.

Aqui se obtienen los datos y estan los dos componentes, un componente es la tabla "TableRenewals" y el otro componente crea una nueva fila en la base de datos "NewRenewalModal"

```
async function getRenewals() {
    const req = await fetch(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL + "/api/renewals/get-renewals", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        cache: 'no-cache',
        next:{revalidate: 1}
    })
    const res = await req.json()
    return res
}

const renewalsData = await getRenewals();
return (
    <>
        <div className="panel">
            <div className="mb-5 flex items-center justify-between">
                <h5 className="text-lg font-semibold dark:text-white-light">Renewalds</h5>
                <div className='flex flex-col gap-4'>
                    <div>
                        <NewRenewalModal />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="datatables">
                <TableRenewals datos={renewalsData} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

Este es el código de NewRenewalModal, intente usar router.refresh() y router.push() para volver a renderizar la tabla que esta de lado del cliente, pero no funciono

```
const submitForm = async () => {
    renewalData.id = Number(renewalData.id);
    renewalData.amount = Number(renewalData.amount);
    renewalData.interest = Number(renewalData.interest);
    renewalData.date = new Date(fecha.toISOString())

    const req = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL + 'api/renewals/create', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            acquisition_id: renewalData.id,
            amount: renewalData.amount,
            interest: renewalData.interest,
            date: renewalData.date,
        }),
    });
    console.log(req.ok)
    console.log(req.status)
    console.log(req.statusText)
    if(req.ok){
        router.refresh();
        router.push('/renewals');
    }
};
```

Esta es la tabla

```
const TableRenewals = ({ datos }: { datos: any}) => {
 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="mb-5 flex justify-end">
                <input type="text" className="form-input w-auto" placeholder="Search..." value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
            </div>
            <DataTable
                striped
                className="table-striped whitespace-nowrap"
                records={recordsData}
                columns={[
                    { accessor: 'id', title: 'ID' },
                    { accessor: 'date', title: 'Fecha' },
                    { accessor: 'amount', title: 'Monto' },
                    { accessor: 'interest', title: 'Interes' },
                    { accessor: 'created_at', title: 'Fecha de creación' },
                    { accessor: 'updated_at', title: 'Fecha de actualización' },
                ]}
                totalRecords={initialRecords.length}
                recordsPerPage={pageSize}
                page={page}
                onPageChange={(p) => setPage(p)}
                recordsPerPageOptions={PAGE_SIZES}
                onRecordsPerPageChange={setPageSize}
                minHeight={200}
                paginationText={({ from, to, totalRecords }) => `Showing  ${from} to ${to} of ${totalRecords} entries`}
            />
        </div>

    );
}

export default TableRenewals;
```